# Why is my CASE not matching in AWS Glue SQL Transform?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to create a column_b depending on whether column_a contains a string such as 'string_1'.
This is for a Transform - SQL Query node in AWS Glue. Here is a sample of my code.

```
select *
,CASE column_a
    WHEN (column_a LIKE '%_string_1%') THEN 'String 1'
    WHEN (column_b LIKE '%_string_2%') THEN 'String 2'
    END AS column_b
from myDataSource
```

Am I missing something?

I have tried to match the exact string and not whether it contains the string or not and still I am not able to catch the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for using a *[searched case expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html)*

You need:

```
select *,
  case
    when column_a like '%_string_1%' then 'String 1'
    when column_b like '%_string_2%' then 'String 2'
  end as column_b
from myDataSource;
```